# Breaking sleep_for

Tags: c++

My application fetches some data on a interval based on polling interval given by user. I am using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds())` in a while loop to sleep for specified polling interval. When user stop the application in console, application will gracefully come out and do some calculations and display the data to user in the console. Below is the logic:

```
BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    switch (dwCtrlType)
    {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        stopFlag = true;
        return TRUE;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

void threadFn()
{
    while (!stopFlag)
    {
        ....
        //collect data and store in a vector
        ....
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(interval)); //user specified value
    }
    
    //accumulate vector values and display in the console
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto th = std::thread(threadFn);
    if (th.joinable())
    {
        th.join();
    }
}
```

When user passes interval time as more i.e. 5+ seconds and stops after some time, I want my application to close within 1 or 2 seconds but due to sleep_for, my application will close only when the interval is lapsed. Is there a way to break sleep_for or when signal is passed? If not, what approach should I use for my requirement?

Comment: Perhaps you should check out condition variables? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: I wanted to suggest signal handlers, but that is not going to be as cross-platform as it is directly interacting with the OS API to register the handler. The suggestion about `condition_variable`'s `wait_for` is doing what you need and is the cross-platform, C++ way to go.

Comment: My data collection should happen at specified interval in a cycle. How this can be done using condition_variable without using sleep?

Comment: @Arun: Using `wait_for` will happen at your interval. Only when your user decides to quit do you set the condition and signal the condition variable.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but that test `if (th.joinable())` isn’t needed. `th` was not default constructed and it wasn’t detached, so it’s joinable.